# VSCode update import on file/folder rename/move doesn't work with alias import in typecript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

**How to configure VSCode to work with alias import in typescript, *specifically* for auto-update import path on file/folder move or rename?**

I've created a repo to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/ran-collective/update-import-bug

moving the folder `api/src/modules/inetgarionA` to `api/src/modules/integrations/inetgarionA` will not work

moving the folder `api/src/modules/inetgarionB` to `api/src/modules/integrations/inetgarionB` will work, and you can see the import changed in `api/src/v1/controller.ts`

the import from integrationA file is path alias, and the import from integrationB is a relative import.